# JQuery XML POST request - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot

I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" message when sending XML request in Jquery (POST).

Can you please tell where am i doing wrong. any pointer on how to send XML request POST in jquery would be of great help

Code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // SUBMIT FORM
    $("#customerForm").submit(function(event) {
        // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
        event.preventDefault();
        ajaxPost();
    });


    function ajaxPost(){

        // PREPARE FORM DATA
        var text;
        xmlRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
            + "<a:InlandDBStructure xmlns:a=\"http://services./inlandpricinglocationretriever/v1\">"
            + "<a:geoids>" + "<a:hubgeoids>"
            + "<a:hubgeoid>12345</a:hubgeoid>"
            + "<a:effectivedt>12-12-2012</a:effectivedt>"
            + "<a:expirydt>12-03-2018</a:expirydt>" + "</a:hubgeoids>"
            + "</a:geoids>" + "</a:InlandDBStructure>";

        if (window.DOMParser)
        {
           parser = new DOMParser();
           xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlRequest, "text/xml");
        }
        else // Internet Explorer
        {
            xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = false;
            xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlRequest);
            console.log("here1: ", xmlDoc);
        }

        console.log("xmlDoc: ", xmlDoc);
        console.log("hub: ", $("#hubgeoid").val());
        // DO POST
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            contentType : "text/xml",
            url : "isInlandPricingLocation",
            data : xmlDoc,
            dataType : 'xml',
            success : function(result) {
                if(result != ""){

                }else{

                }
                console.log(result);
            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert("Error!")
                console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            }
        });

    }

})
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false, So set `processData: false` in your Ajax call.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint, i'm now passing the xml as a string. it worked!